# Can a smooth function always fit between two non-smooth functions?

Tags: continuity, smoothness

Suppose I have two continuous functions, $f$ and $g$, with $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x$ in some closed domain.  Is it always possible to find a (piecewise, if needed) smooth function $h$ such that $f(x)<h(x)<g(x)$ for all $x$?

This is obviously true if either $f$ or $g$ is smooth.  *Proof:* Suppose that $f$ is smooth.  Then $h(x)=f(x)+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is less than $min(g(x)-f(x))$.  This minimum is greater than $0$ because if the limit of $g(x)-f(x)$ approached $0$ at any point, $g(x)$ would equal $f(x)$ at that point (because of continuity).  The argument for $g$ smooth is similar.

But I'm not sure how to do it if neither $f$ nor $g$ is smooth.

Comment: Domain is compact? Then how about taking the average and applying Stone-Weierstrass to approximate the average? As you argued $\frac12 \min(g - f) > 0$, so you just need the polynomial approximant  to be close in uniform norm  to $\frac12 (f+g)$, which you have by Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: @WillieWong And if the domain is not compact you can define $h(x)$ locally and then use a partition of unity

Comment: If the domain is not compact, you can use a partition of unity and perform Willie Wong's construction on some compact sets covering the given one.

Comment: Willie Wong suggests that on a compact domain take a polynomial $h$ such that $|h-(f+g)/2|<(g-f)/2$. Such an $h$ clearly satisfies $f<h<g$. Note that $h$ exists, because the minimum of $(g-f)/2$ is positive on a compact domain.